# How to have a quotation inside a list item in org-mode?

Tags: list, emacs, org-mode, quotations

So, I would like to have something like this:

```
1. This is a list item.
   This is the second line of the list item.
2. This is another list item.
   This is another line of this item.
#+begin_quote
This is a quotation that should belong to the 2nd list item.
#+end_quote
   This is the last line of the 2nd list item.
3. This is the third list item.
```

But `org-mode` understands that the quotation block breaks the list. So my result has a list, a quotation (that does not belong to the list item), and then, another list (with just one item).

Is it possible to do what I want in `org-mode`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you just need to watch the indents and returns. 
This:

```
* Trying to test something
  Here is some text.

  New Paragraph.
** Sub heading for this section
   And some text here.

1. This is a list item.                                                                           
   This is the second line of the list item.                                                      
2. This is another list item.                                                                     
   This is another line of this item.                                                             

   #+begin_quote                                                                                     
   This is a quotation that should belong to the 2nd list item.                                      
   #+end_quote                                                                                       

   This is the last line of the 2nd list item.                                                    
3. This is the third list item.
```

Leaves me with a list like this when exporting as ascii

1. This is a list item. This is the second line of the list item.
2. This is another list item. This is another line of this item.

   ```
    This is a quotation that should belong to the 2nd list
    item.
   ```

   This is the last line of the 2nd list item.
3. This is the third list item.